# How to set up `BaseCallFilter` to only allow a limited set of calls of one pallet to be executed?

Tags: pallet, runtime

Are there examples how to set up a call filter in Substrate to allow *only certain calls of a particular pallet* to be executed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The overarching `Call` enum has the following structure

```rust
enum Call {
    PalletOne(pallet_one::Call),
    PalletTwo(pallet_two::Call),
    // ... and so on
}
```

The implementation of `Contains<Call>` for a call filter can do pattern-matching on the inner values as well. For example,

```rust
impl Contains<Call> for SomeFilter {
    fn contains(call: &Call) -> bool {
        match *call {
            Call::PalletOne(pallet_one::Call::CallA(_)) => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of how we were using a `BaseCallFilter` in the `statemint` parachain to filter out calls that we did not want enabled yet:

https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/2fe7a2edba05155c6a5f0f3527e1001aad7aee2e/polkadot-parachains/statemint/src/lib.rs#L126