# How to restrict ink! contracts code upgrade?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts

What is the best way to disable ink! smart contracts code upgradability for a class of contracts? Below I describe what I need it for, just in case. Thank you!

For my use case, I need my pallet to accept a user-defined algorithm for getting a value used in an extrinsic call handler. As I see, the best way for that case is ink! smart contract. The user provides the contract address and a getter selector to my pallet and then my extrinsic handler can get the value invoking some user-defined code. It may look like this:

```rust
#[pallet::call]
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
  #[pallet::call_index(0)]
  #[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::my_extrinsic())]
  pub fn my_extrinsic(origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResult {
    ensure_signed(origin)?;

    let user_defined = pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::bare_call(<contract address and a value getter selector provided by user earlier>).result?;

    if Self::check(user_defined) {
      Self::do_foo();
    } else {
      Self::do_bar();
    }

    Ok(())
  }
}
```

The problem here is that by default the user may replace the value getter using the [set_code_hash](https://use.ink/basics/upgradeable-contracts#replacing-contract-code-with-set_code_hash), but I want the getter to be non-upgradable and the algorithm never changes.

I can create a fork of the `pallet-contracts` to remove `set_code_hash` from it but is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the recommended approach in your case because you only want to disable a call is to customize the BaseCalleFilter (In [pallet_contract Config](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L282)) to filter out the calls you want to execute.

More on this here: [How to set up `BaseCallFilter` to only allow a limited set of calls of one pallet to be executed?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/how-to-set-up-basecallfilter-to-only-allow-a-limited-set-of-calls-of-one-palle), with an interesting  [example](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/2fe7a2edba05155c6a5f0f3527e1001aad7aee2e/polkadot-parachains/statemint/src/lib.rs#L126) in the responses and here [Whitelist a call subset of a pallet](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6362/whitelist-a-call-subset-of-a-pallet).

If you wanted to add logic on top of the pallet instead of just disable a call, you approach is could work, fork `pallet_contract` and make changes directly to the code but that means that any future updates and improvement to the `pallet_contract` you would have to manually fix it in your pallet.

However in that scenario the recommended approach is to create a new pallet that acts as a "wrapper pallet" for the `pallet_contract` where you can add additional logic on top, in this case you would have to disable all calls from `pallet_contracts` and in your pallet have all calls forwarding to `pallet_contracts` except one. I wrote more about this approach here: [How to customize pallet_contracts?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9788/how-to-customize-pallet-contracts)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As far as I see right now, there are only three ways to change the `user_defined` getter: 1 - [proxy forwarding](https://use.ink/basics/upgradeable-contracts#proxy-forwarding), 2 - [set_code_hash()](https://use.ink/basics/upgradeable-contracts#replacing-contract-code-with-set_code_hash), and 3 - a cross-contract call to an upgradable contract. Hacking around the `CallFilter` looks promising to restrict the first and the second. But a non-upgradable contract still can do cross-contract call an upgradable one. Do you think a custom `ChainExtension` may help with it?